# How to convert array of Object into key/value pair typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, types

Currently I'm getting data in the format below:

```
arr=[
       0: {abc:1},
       1: {efg:2},
       2: {hij:3}
    ]
```

I need it in below format:

```
arr=[
      {name:'abc', value:1},
      {name:'efg', value:2},
      {name:'hij', value:3}]
```

Comment: so start looping and convert it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: This question is lacking content and understanding. It needs to be clarified before it can be answered. Think more in terms of WHAT you want to do, not what should come out of it.

Do you want to access the values in the objects but you don't know the keys?

Comment: Also another question: What happens if you have more than one key and value per object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming an `arr` has a following structure, it's only a matter of mapping through it and separating key and value:

```
var arr = [ 
    {abc:1},
    {efg:2},
    {hij:3}
]

var result = arr.map(o => {
    var k = Object.keys(o)[0];
    return {
        name: k,
        value: o[k]
    };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [  {abc:1}, {efg:2},{hij:3}],
var arr1=[];

      _.forEach(arr, function (val, key) {
        _.forIn(val, function (val, key) {
          arr1.push({ name: key, value: val });
        })
      });
    console.log(arr1);

    });**Implemented using loadash**
```